# Round last value in humanize-duration formatted value (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, postgresql, psql, humanize

I am setting up a table in React that applies [humanize-duration](https://github.com/EvanHahn/HumanizeDuration.js) to a value (the library applies ms and my data is in s, hence the multplier).

```
<td> {humanizeDuration(time_inventoried*1000, { units: ['y', 'mo', 'w', 'd'] }) }</td>
```

The value I'm getting out of this is formatted as such: `10 months, 4 weeks, 0.5540856481481482 days`. **My question is - how can I get that last value to act as an integer, or a shorter float at least?** I've tried converting the psql vaule to integer, as seen below, with no change:

```
SELECT CAST(extract(epoch from (now() - MIN(product_selections.staged_at))) as integer) as time_inventoried
```

I've also tried setting the decimal to '', and got back the error `Reference Error: decimal not defined`.

```
  <td> {humanizeDuration(time_inventoried*1000, { units: ['y', 'mo', 'w', 'd', decimal: ''] }) }</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One day is `24 * 60 * 60` seconds (86400), so to round to a day and convert to ms:

```
Math.round(time_inventoried / 86400) * 86400000
```